# AWS filtering egress traffic

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-security-group

I want to restrict egress traffic for my eks worker nodes deployed in AWS.  I need at least egress rules allow to connect to S3 and ECR. The problem is that I don’t know full pool of IP adresses used by this AWS endpoints. Does anyone have na idea which CIDRs should I set to allow connections to AWS for S3 and ECR access?

Answer (score 0):

You can find IP addresses used by AWS for all its endpoints in AWS docs titled [AWS IP address ranges](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-ip-ranges.html).

Its a long list so you have to search through it to find the IPs of interest. There is also possibility that your services uses more IPs than you can use in security groups.